# How to extrude height segments from a cylinder in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a cylinder that is split into many height segments (the amount depends on the data). For each height segment I have a value for which I want the entire circle at that height to be extruded.

So essentially I end up with a cylinder that has very spiky edges.

I was intending to do this by manually moving the vertices or faces but I cannot seem to access the vertices/faces for a given segment.

So basically I need to scale the segment at N height.

Any suggestions on which direction I take? Have had a few failed attempts now and am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the source code for [CylinderGeometry.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/geometries/CylinderGeometry.js) on GitHub.

You could copy this entire method and call it something different, e.g.

```
 THREE.CylinderGeometry2 = function (...
```

Then change the generation of the vertices based on the number of height segments you have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was considering this but wondered if I had just missed a simple function or a way to select faces at a height segment (which seems quite a useful thing). Just trying to save time really but will give this a go if there are no other quicker suggestions.

Comment: I ended up passing the data as a parametre to a duplicated method that I called THREE.SpinPlot. The important bit was to change the radius (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/geometries/CylinderGeometry.js#L43) to match the data. I also modified the faces (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/geometries/CylinderGeometry.js#L103) so that I could make the colour match the data.

Comment: Those links are to the original source file that I then changed accordingly.